# Hyper link in apex class for Email Body

Tags: apex, visualforce

In My Apex Class am  sending email to user once registration completed. in that email am sending the text with hylerlink as `Click Here to Complete your Registration`

`Click Here` click here should be the Hyper link. but in mail it's send as plain text

```
email.setHtmlBody('Hello ' + FirstName + '<br/><br/>Thanks for registering. This is your Member ID ' + contact.Member_ID__c+'.<br/><br/><a href='+URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl()+'/'+c.id+'>Click Here</a> to Complete your Registration');
```

Kindly help me on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() to work url properly. It will solve your problem

```
email.setHtmlBody('Hello ' + FirstName + '<br/><br/>Thanks for registering. This is your Member ID ' + contact.Member_ID__c+'.<br/><br/><a href="'+URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/'+c.id+'">Click Here</a> to Complete your Registration');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `toExternalForm()` method of URL Class to solve this issue

> `toExternalForm()` :Returns a string representation of the current URL.

Example:
`String MySFURL = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm();` this will return your salesforce URL as a string.

So you can try this:

```
 email.setHtmlBody('Hello ' + FirstName + '<br/><br/>Thanks for registering. This is your Member ID ' + contact.Member_ID__c+'.<br/><br/><a href='+URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/'+c.id+'>Click Here</a> to Complete your Registration');  

OR
  email.setHtmlBody('Hello ' + FirstName + '<br/><br/>Thanks for registering. This is your Member ID ' + contact.Member_ID__c+'.<br/><br/><a href="'+URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/'+c.id+'">Click Here</a> to Complete your Registration');
```

Both of the code should work.